# Asp.net Webforms - Using ScriptManager/Proxy to add Bundled Javascript to Both Top and Bottom of Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, scriptmanager

I would like to use the built-in asp.net ScriptManager/ScriptManagerProxy controls to add bundled javascript code to both the top AND the bottom of the page. I have some code I want to load near the top of the page and other code that shouldn't run until after the DOM has been created. Is there a way to direct the ScriptManager/ScriptManagerProxy where to add a bundle (i.e. scriptA at top and script at the bottom of the page)? Ideally I would like to do this declaratively rather than adding it to the code behind. I am using webforms.

Comment: [RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend: http://www.niksofteng.com/2012/11/registerstartupscript-vs.html

Comment: The problem with RegisterStartupScript is that as far as I can tell, 1. it can't be done declaratively, it is done in the code behind and 2. it doesn't reconnect after a partial page load, that's why you have to use the ScriptManager. I've used RegisterStartupScript before, but for these reasons I didn't want to go that route this time. (Unless I'm wrong?)